# How to delete Xbox Game Bar app?

Tags: windows-10

I want to delete an app called "Xbox Game Bar" on my computer (my version is Windows 10). When I tried to go to settings to uninstall the app, the uninstall button is grayed out and I am unable to click it. Does anybody else have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried uninstalling the app "Xbox Game Bar" with an application that I use called "IObit Uninstaller", and it was a success.

You will have have to install the application and then look under the "Windows Apps" for the "Xbox Game Bar" to show up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows 10 1909, you can use powershell.

Run PowerShell.exe as administrator and run the following:

```
    $xboxapps = Get-ProvisionedAppxPackage -Online | Where-Object { $_.PackageName - 
    like "*xbox*" }
    ForEach ($app in $xboxapps) {
    Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage -Online -PackageName $app.PackageName
    }
```